# A function is pulling variable values from a different function, but I don't want it to and don't know how it's doing it

Tags: c, function, variables, scope, int

For my programming class we are making a main() function that calls multiple other functions. Two of these functions are numberStats() and triad(), both of which have their own variables, no global variables are used, and numberStats() is called immediately before triad(). Neither codes have similar variable names, but for some reason when I use the triad function, which asks the user to input 3 ints, it spits out the first int correctly but the 2nd and 3rd ints are the two ints inputted into the numberStats() function. Can anyone explain why this is happening and what I might be able to do to fix it? Thank you in advance, new blood here.
   EDIT*
here's the output code: (if it's italicized then it's the numbers I entered in as input)

```
    numberStats: Please enter two positive ints: 5 800  //I input 5 and 800

    800 is larger
    5 is smaller
    800 + 5 = 805
    800 - 5 = 795
    800 * 5 = 4000
    800 % 5 = 0

    triad: Please enter three positive ints:
    1 2 3    //I input 1 2 and 3
    you entered 1, 5, and 800
    Not all equal
    Sorted order: 1, 5, 800
```

I obviously did not enter 1, 5, and 800 for the triad function, why would it tell me I did?

EDIT** Source code for numberStats() and triad():

```
    void numberStats(void)
{
    int var1, var2, a, b, c, d;

    printf("numberStats: Please enter two positive ints: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&var1, &var2);

    if (var1 > var2){
            printf("%d is larger\n",var1);
            printf("%d is smaller\n",var2);

    a = var1 + var2;
    b = var1 - var2;
    c = var1 * var2;
    d = var1 % var2;

            printf("%d + %d = %d\n",var1,var2,a);
            printf("%d - %d = %d\n",var1,var2,b);
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n",var1,var2,c);
            printf("%d %% %d = %d\n",var1,var2,d);
    }
    else if (var1 < var2){
            printf("\n%d is larger\n",var2);
            printf("%d is smaller\n",var1);

    a = var2 + var1;
    b = var2 - var1;
    c = var2 * var1;
    d = var2 % var1;

            printf("%d + %d = %d\n",var2,var1,a);
            printf("%d - %d = %d\n",var2,var1,b);
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n",var2,var1,c);
            printf("%d %% %d = %d\n",var2,var1,d);
    }
    else if (var1 == var2){
            printf("%d and %d are the same\n",var1,var2);

    a = var1 + var2;
    b = var1 - var2;
    c = var1 * var2;
    d = var1 % var2;

            printf("%d + %d = %d\n",var1,var2,a);
            printf("%d - %d = %d\n",var1,var2,b);
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n",var1,var2,c);
            printf("%d %% %d = %d\n",var1,var2,d);
    }
}

void triad(void)
{
    int x, y, z, low, mid, high;

    printf("\ntriad: Please enter three positive ints: \n");
    scanf("%d, %d, %d", &x, &y, &z);
    printf("you entered %d, %d, and %d\n", x, y, z);

    if (x == y && y == z){
            printf("All equal\n");
    }
    if (x <= y && x <= z){
            low = x;
            if (y <= z){
                    mid = y;
                    high = z;
            }
            else{
                    mid = z;
                    high = y;
            }
            printf("Not all equal\n");
    }
    if (x >= y && x >= z){
            high = x;
            if (y <= z){
                    low = y;
                    mid = z;
            }
            else{
                    low = z;
                    mid = y;
            }
            printf("Not all equal\n");
    }
    if ((x >= y && x <= z) || (x <= y && x >= z)){
            mid = x;
            if (y >= z){
                    high = y;
                    low = z;
            }
            else{
                    high = z;
                    low = y;
            }
            printf("Not all equal\n");
    }
    printf("Sorted order: %d, %d, %d\n", low, mid, high);
}
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful

Comment: You are probably using uninitialized variables, or reading beyond the bounds of your allocated memory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. There are all sorts of things that might be going wrong, but which particular one you've chosen to use is going to be impossible to guess (except by lucky chance) without any code to look at.  Please provide an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `triad()` and `scanf()` are causing the trouble:

```
int x, y, z, low, mid, high;

printf("\ntriad: Please enter three positive ints: \n");
scanf("%d, %d, %d", &x, &y, &z);
```

You're looking for commas in the data, but not entering them (you gave "`1 2 3`" but you needed to give "`1,2,3`" with commas (and optional spaces) separating the numbers).  `scanf()` returned `1` instead of `3`, but you ignored it.  Don't!  Check your inputs, every time.

As a result, you have quasi-random values in `y` and `z`, which is why you're running into problems.

A basic debugging technique is to print the values just read:

```
if (scanf("%d, %d, %d", &x, &y, &z) != 3)
   …report error and bail out…
printf("x = %d, y = %d, z = %d\n", x, y, z);
```

Comment: Oh my lord Thank you! I don't know why I put those commas in there, thank you so much! That debugging technique does sound very helpful, I hadn't heard of it. Thank you very much for helping a begginer!

Comment: Please notice that it was easy to solve your problem with the code to study and difficult to help you without it.  The 800 was probably left over on the stack after `numberStats()` returned, which is why it appeared; the `5` too.  But that was coincidence.  Had you called, say, `printf()` in between the calls to `numberStats()` and `triad()`, you would have seen other values altogether.

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't make sense to not add the source code, I'm not sure why I didn't the first time.

Comment: No problem as long as you've learned for next time.  Please do look at the MCVE and SSCCE links in my comment to the question; they do provide valuable advice.

Comment: I have and will, thank you for being patient with me, it's always noticed and appreciated whether you feel it is or not.